# C# Multiple progress bars for multiple file downloads

Tags: c#, progress-bar, webclient

I am writing a C# application for uploading and downloading file. The download uses WebClient object and its `DownloadAsycDownload` method. The download works fine for multiple files. It downloads as much files as I want.

My problem is I am not able to show the progress of all file in different progress bars which are dynamically added to the form's `flowlayout control`.

**Here is my code:**

```
public ProgressBar[] bar;
public int countBar=0;

...

    bar[countBar] = new ProgressBar();
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(bar[countBar]);
    countBar++;

    request.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownoadInProgress);
    request.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
    request.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.uri), localPath);

    byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(this.uri);
    FileStream file = File.Create(localPath);
    file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    file.Close();
}

public void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(bar[countBar]);
    countBar--;
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
}

public void DownoadInProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bar[countBar].Maximum = total_bytes;
    bar[countBar].Value = (int)e.BytesReceived;                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a count to index into progress bars, but once one is complete - you remove the last one, where you really should remove the one associated with the file.

I suggest, in this case, using a `Dictionary<WebClient, ProgressBar>` (might not be `WebCliet` - should be the type of `sender` in the events).

```
...
var progBar = new ProgressBar();
progBar.Maximum = 100;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(progBar);

request.DownloadProgressChanged += DownoadInProgress;
request.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted;
request.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.uri), localPath);

dic.Add(request, progBar);

// You shouldn't download the file synchronously as well!
// You're already downloading it asynchronously.

// byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(this.uri);
// FileStream file = File.Create(localPath);
// file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
// file.Close();
```

Then, you can remove `countBar` altogether, and have the new methods:

```
public void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Can remove (WebClient) cast, if dictionary is <object, ProgressBar>
    var request = (WebClient)sender;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(dic[request]);
    dic.Remove(request);
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
}

public void DownoadInProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var progBar = dic[(WebClient)sender];
    progBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;                
}
```

Comment: If this helped you entirely, mark as accepted answer. Otherwise, let me know what's missing.

Comment: I am trying to add the components from another class.Could not get the progress bar added to the form at run time. These methods which I posted are in another class.

Comment: No Error. But does not add the progress bar at run time. The progress bars should be added on button click.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted it here is the link if you have some thought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338447/c-sharp-adding-control-from-another-class

Comment: You should use ProgressPercentage instead of casting bytes to int.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this with lambdas, a bit more concise, no need in dictionary:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

var pb = new ProgressBar();
pb.Maximum = 100;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);

webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, args) =>
{
    pb.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
};

webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, args) =>
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(pb);
};

webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.uri), localPath);
```