# C# adding control from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance, controls

I want to add form controls dynamically to my form from another class which inherits the form class. Everything works fine but it does not add the controls at run time.

Here is my sample code:

```
namespace Namespace1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    .....

  }

 .......
 }// end of Namespace1

namespace Namespace2
{
public class1:Form1
{
public Button button = new Button();

public void method1()
  {
   button1.Name="button1";
  //flowlayoutcontrol1 is a public control on Form1
  flowlayoutcontrol1.Controls.Add(button1);
  }
```

}
}

Comment: You need to call the method "method1" in the constructor or in the Form's "Load" event

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.But is is the only way? Because on the real code the "method1" has parameters, which will automatically start downloading something from server and needs location(which is not possible for me now to give the location at the constructor or load even of the form).

Comment: split method1 up a bit more to include another method that can be separated to serve this function

Comment: @Sayse thanks for the effort. But my application is throwing stackOverflow exception.

Comment: How? what has changed?

Comment: @Sayse, sorry my bad. I added the method inside the conductor. Now I added it it inside the form load, the application is running okey. But I could not get the controls added on the form still. I created a middle method as you suggested.

Comment: can you update your question please with the updates

Comment: @Sayse My plan is to add control(progressBar) at run time dynamically from another class. I get replay saying I need to call the method from the form class. I did that but I get no change. Thanks again for the concern.